# Android ViewModel in PreferenceFragmentCompat

Tags: android, android-jetpack

This is my first jetpack app with android and kotlin, so I'm fairly unexperienced.

Following the Google's guideline on how to manage data, I created a viewmodel which downloads from my api some data.

Now I need to show that data inside a ListPreference inside a PreferenceFragmentCompat class:

```
override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
    setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.texts, rootKey)
    this.language = findPreference("language")

    homeViewModel.languagesAndPropers.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, this.observer)
}
```

the method `observe(...)` is not firing, so its callback (`this.observer` in my case) never run.

**Edit:**
this is the observer detail

```
private val observer = Observer<Result<Item>> {
    when (it.status) {
      Status.LOADING -> > Toast.makeText(context, "loading", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
      Status.ERROR -> Toast.makeText(context, it.error!!.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
      Status.SUCCESS -> {
          // do something with the data
      }
   }
}
```

**Edit 2:** here's the definition for languageandpropers

```
class HomeViewModel(private val repo: LanguagesAndPropersRepository) : ViewModel() {
    private val _lp = MediatorLiveData<Resource<LanguagesAndPropers>>()
    private var lpSource: LiveData<Resource<LanguagesAndPropers>> = MutableLiveData()

    val languagesAndPropers: LiveData<Resource<LanguagesAndPropers>> get() = _lp


    init {
        getLP(false)
    }

    fun refresh() {
        getLP(true)
    }

    private fun getLP(forceRefresh: Boolean) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        _lp.removeSource(lpSource) // We make sure there is only one source of live data (allowing us properly refresh)
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { lpSource = repo.getLanguagesAndPropers(forceRefresh) }
        _lp.addSource(lpSource) {
            _lp.value = it
        }
    }
}
```

I dunno what's missing in my code.

Comment: what is `this.observer`

Comment: have you instantiated the `ViewModel` correctly? Are you doing `languageAndPropers.postValue(Result.LOADING)` or `languageAndPropers.setValue(Result.LOADING)` or something?

Comment: please show the definition of languageAndPropers

Comment: Edited the answer with the home view model definition

Comment: How are you instantiating your ViewModel?

Comment: @RahulShukla by injecting it via koin viewModel()
`private val homeViewModel: HomeViewModel by viewModel()`

Answer (score 2):

i know its late but maybe useful for others

use your
`viewModel` inside `onViewCreated`

```
    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.texts, rootKey)
     }

     override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

            val language : Preference? = findPreference("language")

            homeViewModel.languagesAndPropers.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
                 // do something with languagesAndPropers value
            })
     }
```